# How to fix this Powershell script using Get-WmiObject?

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I have this piece of code that gets the information from the computers in the domain and outputs to a csv file. I tried to add a new line of code to also grab t he Disk information for the computers but I can't get it working as expected.

```
# Get the list of all computer names and export to CSV file
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | select Name | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\computers.csv' -NoTypeInformation

# Import the computer names from CSV file and get the system information
$computers = Import-Csv “C:\Temp\computers.csv” | ForEach {

    $computerSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_.Name
    $computerOS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.Name
    $computerCPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $_.Name
    $computerSN = Get-WmiObject Win32_bios -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object SerialNumber
    $computerDisk = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object DeviceId

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'PCName' = $computerSystem.Name    
        'Model' = $computerSystem.Model   
        'RAM' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB)    
        'CPU' = $computerCPU.Name    
        'OS' = $computerOS.caption   
        'SN' = $computerSN.SerialNumber
        'User' = $computerSystem.UserName 
        'Disk' = $computerDisk.DeviceId | Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
    }

} | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\system-info.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

This is the line of codes for disk.

```
$computerDisk = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object DeviceId
```

And...

```
'Disk' = $computerDisk.DeviceId | Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
```

The other parameters work but only the disk info section isn't working. the output is: `System.Object[]` instead of displaying the info .

Comment: `win32_logicaldisk` returns a collection of drives because a computer can have multiple drives. So you need a foreach loop iterating over each drive

Comment: What exactly do you expect that `Disk` row in the CSV to look like?

Comment: Under Disk column, I need the Disk letter (D:, E:, etc), capacity and free size in GB, maybe It needs 3 columns but I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked or me somewhat but it only grabs the info for the first drive. Also, the free space is larger than the Disk size which is weird.

```
$Computers = Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\computers.csv'

$Computers | ForEach {

    $computerSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_.Name
    $computerOS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.Name
    $computerCPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $_.Name
    $computerSN = Get-WmiObject Win32_bios -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object SerialNumber
    $computerDisk = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object DeviceId, Size, FreeSpace

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'PCName' = $computerSystem.Name    
        'Model' = $computerSystem.Model   
        'RAM' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB)    
        'CPU' = $computerCPU.Name    
        'OS' = $computerOS.caption   
        'SN' = $computerSN.SerialNumber
        'User' = $computerSystem.UserName 
        'Disk' = $computerDisk.DeviceId  | Format-Table | Out-String
        'Size' = $computerDisk.Size  | Format-Table | Out-String
        'Free Space' = $computerDisk.FreeSpace  | Format-Table | Out-String
    }

} | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\system-info.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the result I think you're after:

```
$Computers = Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\computers.csv'

$Computers | ForEach {

    $computerSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_.Name
    $computerOS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.Name
    $computerCPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $_.Name
    $computerSN = Get-WmiObject Win32_bios -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object SerialNumber
    $computerDisk = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'PCName' = $computerSystem.Name    
        'Model' = $computerSystem.Model   
        'RAM' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB)    
        'CPU' = $computerCPU.Name    
        'OS' = $computerOS.caption   
        'SN' = $computerSN.SerialNumber
        'User' = $computerSystem.UserName 
        'Disk' = $computerDisk | Format-Table | Out-String
    }

} | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\system-info.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The first problem was that in the `$computerDisk =` line you were using `Select-Object` to return only the `DeviceID` property, but then were later trying to use the other properties.

The second problem was that you need to pipe `Format-Table` to `Out-String` when you output it to convert it to string format so that `Export-CSV` doesn't treat it as an object.

Comment: The Disk column is blank. Not sure why.

Comment: Let's make it simpler. i just need the DeviceId, capacity and free space. No need for Media type. I think since every computer has multiple drives, then the disk out put comes out as null. Since disk output is trying to add the info into 1 column only. Am  I right?

Comment: Are you opening it in Excel to check? Because the top line is blank so at first it looks empty but it's multiline so just expand the row and it should be there.

Comment: Yes, it's completely blank.

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: It works OK for me, both on Windows 10 and 7. Are you using my code exactly as written?

Comment: Everything works but the Disk info section. Do you think a foreach loop is needed for disk info?

Comment: I don't think its the root of your problem, because I am able to get output for Disk info when I use the code above. I think you should try running the `Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}` park on its own and see if you are getting any output at all.

Comment: it comes up with error: 'Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:1 char:162
+ ... Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace"‌​;e={[math]:: ...'

Comment: It works if I use the command below: ' Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk  | Select-Object DeviceId, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}'